# Android Gradle Sync Failure after updating to version 4.10

Tags: android, gradle

After updating AndroidStudio, Gradle and `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to new version i get this error:

```
org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel
```

***gradle.properties:***

```
#Mon Feb 18 21:35:48 IRST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

**project Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}


ext {
    VERSION = version()
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


task version {
    println version()
}

def String version() {
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    return versionProps['major'] + "." + versionProps['minor'] + "." + versionProps['patch']
}
```

**and then app gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed application couldn't run and i get only this like during build process: `org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel`

Comment: Would you please try to remove Kotlin plugin and sync again?

Comment: Hello @DolDurma, did u solved this? I'm also facing the same issue :(

Comment: @ppreetikaa here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589610/gradle-sync-failure-after-updating-to-version-4-10-1-4-10-2)

Comment: @DolDurma please have to look at this [doc](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000666624-Cannot-sync-Gradle-Kotlin-project-with-2017-3-Public-Preview) and also [this](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Kotlin plugin.

The simple way (Recommended).

`Double shift -> Plugins -> Updates -> search Kotlin -> Update! -> Restart AS`

Manually way (If you need).

1) Download Kotlin Plugin manually from this link.

2) Double shift -> Plugins -> (Settings) Icon -> Install from disk -> Choose that plugin.

3) Restart Android Studio.