# AndroidStudio fails to sync Gradle files

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

Recently, AndroidStudio stopped working for me.

If I sync to gradle files, I get this error:

**Gradle sync failed: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel**

The log:

```
2019-03-05 14:32:47,370 [d thread 7]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateKaptKotlinGeneratedSourceDir(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:359)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:250)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:95)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:383)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$100(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:879)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:863)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:573)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:678)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2019-03-05 14:32:47,370 [d thread 7]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel 
2019-03-05 14:32:47,370 [d thread 7]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModelorg/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptGradleModel
```

When Googling this error, people mention to re-install the Kotlin plugin.

But here is the thing: I have never installed a Kotlin plugin. I don't use Kotlin, I only use NDK and Java.

This has always worked just fine.

Did AndroidStudio recently added a requirement on the Kotlin plugin? Am I now forced to install Kotlin?

**UPDATE**

`$ rm -rf ~/.gradle` solution did not help.

Menu option ***Invalidate Caches / Restart*** did not help.

A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803630/301166) offered from a related question (**upgrade to Gradle 5.2.1**) did not help.

OS: Ubuntu LTS

AndroidStudio version:3.3.2

top level gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.steenriver.armor"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 134
        versionName "1.34"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cFlags "-DCP_USE_DOUBLES=0 -DCP_USE_CGTYPES=0"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -DANDROID=1 -DPLAY=1 -DUSEES3=1 -DLOGTAG=armor -DCP_USE_DOUBLES=0 -DCP_USE_CGTYPES=0 -DAPPVER=$versionName"
                arguments "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=0", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
        }
        debug {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags += "-DDEBUG"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path '../../Android/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
    api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Sync Failure after updating to version '4.10.1'/'4.10.2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589610/gradle-sync-failure-after-updating-to-version-4-10-1-4-10-2)

Comment: it is difficult to tell, while you only post the stack-trace, but not the `build.gradle` which produces it... would assume it to be related to `apply plugin 'kotlin-kapt'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried many things, but the only way I was able to make this error go away, is by **enabling the Kotlin plug-in**.

[image: settings]

This I find strange, because:

- It used to work fine without the Kotlin plugin before.
- I don't use any Kotlin code, anywhere. Just Java, C and C++.

I suspect Android Studio picked up a false dependency on Kotlin somewhere, recently. This is unfortunate. I don't see why this plug-in would be required.

Comment: interesting. since `Kotlin` received first-class support in Android Studio, I also have to enforce a certain version of `kotlin-stdlib` in Java/JNI projects, just to get rid of a warning message.

Comment: This absolutely the same case happened on me. Android Studio can't even create a project when kotlin is disabled. Seems that the Android Developer want to force everybody migrate to kotlin.

Comment: could you help to submit a bug to Android Studio:  https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs to track it? sounds odd, thanks!